# How to calculate time difference in 24 hour format across midnight

Tags: javascript, time, format, difference

I am calculating time difference between two time in 24 hour format. Here I have a case where start time is 22 which is 10 pm and end time is 6 which is 6 am of another day. I am trying if initial time is greater than end time than (24 - start time)+ end Time. But how exactly do this in the case of time like hh:mm by ignoring seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

Hours

```js
const diff = (s, e) => s > e ? Math.abs(s - 24 - e) : e - s;

console.log(diff(22, 6))

console.log(diff(6, 22))
```

HH:MM

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const diff = (s, e) => {
  const [shh, smm] = s.split(":");
  const [ehh, emm] = e.split(":");
  const smin = +smm + (60 * shh);
  const emin = +emm + (60 * ehh);
  let mDiff = s > e ? Math.abs(smin - (24 * 60) - emin) : emin - smin;
  let hours = Math.floor(mDiff / 60);
  let minutes = mDiff % 60;
  return pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes)
}


console.log(diff("22:03", "06:04"))
console.log(diff("06:04", "22:03"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use moment library.

Something like

moment().subtract(1,'days').startOf('day').toString()

moment().subtract(1,'days').endOf('day').toString()